# Spring Converter - cyclic issue

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, jaxb, jersey

I have a issue where, I have a converter class say called aConverter as such:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "aConverter")
public class aConverter implements ConverterBase{

      private A a;
      private Set<B> bs;
      /// some constructor code here
      ...
      @XmlElement(name="B")
      public Set<B> getBs() {
                bs = a.getBs();
                return bs;
      }

      public void setBs(Set<B> bs) {
                a.setBs(bs);
      }
}
```

Class A and B are defined respectively in a cyclic fashion:

```
public class A {
       private Set <B> bs;

       //constructor code here
       ... 

       public Set<B> getBs() {
          return this.bs;
       }
       public void setBs(Set<B> bs) {
          this.bs = bs;
       }
}
```

>

```
public class B {
       private A a;

       // some constructor code here
       ...

       public A getA() {
              return this.a;
       }
       public void setA(A a) {
              this.a = a;
       }
}
```

Now, when I the webservice I'm seeing the following error:

[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: B@1105452 -> A@1 -> B@1105452]
 at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:152)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:294)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1140)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1053)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1043)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:406)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:477)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:

I'm really out of ideas here, any feeback on this would be really nice.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) we introduced the @XmlInverseReference extension to solve this issue.  For an example of how this can be leveraged in a JAX-RS service check out:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@XmlTransient` annotation. See [this page](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.5-2/docs/ch03.html#annotating-your-classes-mapping-cyclic-references-to-xml) for more.